# Dash Dropdown with only 1 option, is there a way to select it automatically?

Tags: python, dropdown, plotly-dash

I am using Dash with Python to program a dropdown in which sometimes the possible options (labels and value) only contain one value. For that case, is there anyway to autofill the dropdown so that the user does not have to click on the unique option? Or maybe is there another better alternative to the dropdown in that case?

In the case of len(initial) == 1, I would like the dropdown to be selected automatically to the only possible value.

```
@app.callback(Output('output', 'children'),
             Input('upload', 'filename'),
)
def selection(initial):
    if len(initial) == 1:
        return html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(id='selected-dd',data={'label':initial[0], 'value':initial[0]}),
            ])
    else:
        return html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(id='selected-dd',options=[{'label':x, 'value':x} for x in initial]),
            ])
```

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your current solution to set the `value` in the callback looks good to me. Is it not working? You haven't shared enough code to reproduce an example.